# System.TypeLoadException error on Asp.Net MVC Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, mono, visual-studio-mac

My company gave me a Macbook for gift. I am trying to transfer my ASP.NET MVC version 4.7 project to Visual Studio for Mac but i am getting this error. Can you help me to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft only supports ASP.NET on Windows, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-5.0 You have to migrate to ASP.NET Core if you want to stay on Mac.

Comment: Please update Mono to latest stable. Seems to be running an older version.